# How to pass argv inputs from one python script with parameters to one without?

Tags: python, bash, input, parameters, argv

I am dealing with large sensor data structures stored in FITS-files which I open and read-in using the astropy module.
For analysis I have written several scripts (e.g. `analysis1.py`) that deal with this data in different ways - each one creating an image file with several subplots.

Now I want to create an `init.py` script that initializes things like, filename and several parameters for analysis like this

```
init.py filename arg2 arg3 arg4
```

This I want to pass then to all subscripts, e.g. `analysis1.py`

```
#analysis1.py

from init import filename, arg2, arg3, arg4

# import everything else necessary

# do things with the data
# output picture as png-file
```

using bash but without explicitely inputting these as arguments again like

```
#!/bin/bash
# initialization of parameters and data read-in
python init.py filename arg2 arg3 arg4

# analysis scripts running in parallel using the parameters of init.py
python analysis1.py &
python analysis3.py &
```

I use this way because I'm usually working on CPU-machines and want to use as many threads/cores as possible to be efficient.

Common importing of course doesn't work because there `argv` doesn't get the parameters from the last run

```
import init
from sys import argv

print(argv)
#returns ['mypath/init.py']
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Unless the `init.py` script changes something on the disc, there is no way the arguments you pass into it at the start can be preserved. Why can't you just call all the analysis scripts with the same arguments and have every script parse them independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kendas says, you will have to persist the arguments on disk somewhere.

This will work:

**init.py**

```
import sys
import pickle

def get_parms():
    return pickle.load(open("init.dat","rb"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myparms = sys.argv[:]
    pickle.dump(myparms,open("init.dat","wb"))
```

**analysis1.py**

```
import init
myparms = init.get_parms()
print(myparms)
```

If you run `init.py` like this:

```
python init.py filename arg1 arg2 arg3
```

then `analysis1.py` will produce this output:

```
['(pathname)/init.py', 'filename', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

You will almost certainly want to allow `analysis1.py` to accept command line parameters as overrides to the values from `init`.

Answer (score 0):

If you called your bash script with all your input parameters:

```
./mybash.sh filename arg2 arg3 arg4
```

Then you could write your bash script like this to pass your input parameters to all your scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
# initialization of parameters and data read-in
python init.py $1 $2 $3 $4

# analysis scripts running in parallel using the parameters of init.py
python analysis1.py $1 $2 $3 $4 &
python analysis3.py $1 $2 $3 $4 &
```

Your init.py would then have access to the parameters in sys.argv:

```
# init.py

from sys import argv

print(argv)
# prints ['mypath/init.py', <filename>, <arg2>, <arg3>, <arg4>]

# everything else
```

Same for your analysis scripts:

```
# analysis1.py

from sys import argv

print(argv)
# prints ['mypath/analysis1.py', <filename>, <arg2>, <arg3>, <arg4>]

# everything else
```

**EDIT**
If the goal is to have your init.py take the initial input parameters to the bash script, change them and then pass those changed values on to the analytics scripts as parameters, then you could have your init.py script dump them in eg JSON format to stdout so that your analytics scripts could parse them at start-up.

To do that, change your init.py to dump the initialised parameters to stdout, eg:

```
# init.py

import json
from sys import argv

# assign your input parameters
init_filename = argv[1]
init_arg2 = argv[2]
init_arg3 = argv[3]
init_arg4 = argv[4]

# do some initialisation on your input parameters here

# dump your initialised parameters to stdout in json format
print(json.dumps([init_filename, init_arg2, init_arg3, init_arg4]))
```

Then let your analytics scripts parse the JSON values at start-up:

```
# analysis1.py

import json
from sys import argv

print(json.loads(argv[1]))
# prints [<init_filename>, <init_arg2>, <init_arg3>, <init_arg4>]

# everything else
```

Finally, assign the (JSON) output from your init.py script to a variable and pass that to the analytics scripts in your bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# initialization of parameters and data read-in
PARAMS=$(python init.py $1 $2 $3 $4)

# analysis scripts running in parallel using the parameters dumped by init.py
python analysis1.py ''"$PARAMS"'' 
python analysis3.py ''"$PARAMS"''
```

You could probably do this without JSON, but then you'd have to worry about ascaping spaces and special characters in your filename and args that you dump to stdout.